# Leetcode SQL Problem: Calculate the cancellation rate in Uber - their solution is incorrect?

Tags: sql

This is the 11th out of 12 test case in this [SQL Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trips-and-users/description/).

I do not think their answer key is correct. The below is the input and my output vs. what is expected (their answer key).

Please let me know if I'm misreading/overlooking anything. To me, it looks like there was a total of 1 cancellation out of a total of 1 trip. Therefore, a 100% cancellation rate. The answer key just produces a blank.

Input

```
Trips =
| id | client_id | driver_id | city_id | status              | request_at |
| -- | --------- | --------- | ------- | ------------------- | ---------- |
| 1  | 1         | 10        | 1       | cancelled_by_client | 2013-10-04 |
Users =
| users_id | banned | role   |
| -------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1        | No     | client |
| 10       | No     | driver |

My Output
| Day        | Cancellation Rate |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 2013-10-04 | 1                 |
```

Expected

```
| Day | Cancellation Rate |
| --- | ----------------- |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the task is said:

*Write a SQL query to find the cancellation rate of requests with unbanned users (both client and driver must not be banned) each day between "2013-10-01" and "2013-10-03". Round Cancellation Rate to two decimal points.*

Your test data is from `2013-10-04`, so it's normal for the initial (their answer) the expected result to be `no data`.

Comment: Knew i was overlooking something. Thanks for the catch!!